# Editing question after answer

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and was told I might have better luck posting it on  Code Review. I posted the question on both sites with a link to both questions stating that I was told I may have better luck there, and after about five minutes I got an answer on Stack Overflow that completely answered my question regarding speed up time, and dropped the process speed to under thirty seconds.

If I don't have an answer on this question already, but do have a vote, can I completely refactor my question to a new one to include the question I asked in the first place? Or would I need to post a completely separate question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to edit part(s) of code not yet reviewed?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/752/is-it-okay-to-edit-parts-of-code-not-yet-reviewed)

Comment: Your upvotes are not *really* that important! Ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how much of the original question survives.

If I understand you correctly, your question got answered quite nicely. If the revised question would simply be a sub-set of the original question, an edit could suffice. If the focus of the question shifts completely and the code has been heavily re-written, a new question would be the way to go.

There's a grey area in the middle. I'd error on the side of caution and post a new question when in doubt.